# How To create a FreeBSD 10 bootable USB?

Tags: boot, freebsd, live-usb

Currently I am Using Linux Mint 17 and I want to dual boot FreeBSD and Linux Mint 17.

How can I create Bootable USB for FreeBSD 10?  I tried **Unetbootin**, **Image writer** and **powerISO** but it's not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please download [memstick image](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/i386/ISO-IMAGES/10.0/FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-i386-memstick.img) from [here](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/i386/ISO-IMAGES/10.0/) (or you can use [amd64](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.0/FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img) of course). Attach the pendrive and write the img file with [dd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?dd%281%29):

```
dd if=your_img_file.img of=/dev/device_name_of_pendrive bs=512
```

The `device_name_of_pendrive` is the device name of pendrive, NOT partition! (e.g. `/dev/sdc` and not `/dev/sdc1` or similar)

Comment: why bs is 512?.

Comment: It can be 10240 as the announce wrote ( https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.0R/announce.html ).

Comment: why bs is 512?.