# FreeBSD bootable usb

Tags: linux, freebsd, usb-drive

How can I make a bootable USB stick with FreeBSD on it and then boot the image from Plop Linux? (I am using Linux mint)
I want to install this OS ,also I want to know if Plop will detect the the BSD image.

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159264/how-to-create-a-freebsd-10-bootable-usb/159372#159372

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what you mean by a USB stick with FreeBSD on it.
Do you mean a FreeBSD installer or do you mean a Live FreeBSD version ?

If you want a FreeBSD install download a *memstick.img* version from [here](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.1/).

If you want a Live FreeBSD version download a *image* from [here](http://www.livebsd.com/#FreeBSD_Live_CDs).

After downloading dump the image to your USB stick with the `dd` command:

```
dd if=~/freebsd-memstick.img of=/dev/usb bs=1M
```

*usb* can be also `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`... Check first which drive letter your USB stick will have, otherwise you can delete a wrong drive.